# Using Google Transit mode in Android Google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Currently working in Google Map App.I want to use Google transit API in android application. I am using like this.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=77.589355,13.004558&destination=78.655758,11.253837&mode=transit&sensor=false&region=fr&departure_time=1387069950

What is departure_time? How can I find. All the details I'm getting dynamically(the user choices).

```
<li>
    String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?" + 
                 "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude + 
                 "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude + 
                 "&sensor =false &units=metric&mode=trnsit......."
</li>
```

like this I'm using.

Can anyone please help me with

- How can I find departure time dynamically and
- where can I get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format you are looking for is the number of seconds elapsed since 1st January 1970, sometimes called "Unix time".

The Date class includes the [getTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) method to get this value.  Try something like this:

```
import java.util.*;

Date departure = new Date();  // This is the current time for testing purposes

String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=" +
    start.latitude + "," + start.longitude + "&destination=" + end.latitude +
    "," + end.longitude + "&mode=transit&sensor=false&region=fr&departure_time=" +
    departure.getTime();
```